# Android : Text Image button

Tags: android, xml, button, imagebutton

I try to create a button with a wooden-like texture.
Also I want some text to be written on it.
I couldnt figure out how to add text on an image button or alternatively to add an image to a regular button.

Comment: Can You Update Your Question and provide a specific image for an example ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create two views (one above another) like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton 
        ...
    />

    <TextView 
        ...
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

Or you can create a regular button with an image in background (maybe remove border):

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/image"
    android:text="text"
/>
```